# How to use custom Jackson JsonDeserializer<T> class on specific object within JSON structure?

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

I want to write a custom JSON deserializer for my project, I don't want to parse out the entire document in the deserializer, just the part that I want to use the custom deserializer on.

This is the JSON I would like to parse: http://pastebin.com/mkHy0Gj6

Currently, when I try to use a custom deserializer, all of the document is passed along and I have to manually parse everything, I just want to have to do this for the objects within the events array. How can I do this?

Here is my current implementation: http://pastebin.com/dePz0QFJ

Comment: Why do you want to write a custom deserializer? That appears, on the face of it, to easily be deserializable using databinding

Comment: I can't post the exact JSON I'm working with since its got some of my information on it, I'm trying to parse something from the Steam API actually. That is the structure of what I'm trying to parse via the deserializer though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the annotation

`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

to your custom deserializer and it will ignore everything but the fields you choose to deserialize.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, this is what I have so far... http://pastebin.com/dePz0QFJ I get this error: "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Root name 'name' does not match expected ('JsonNode') for type [simple type, class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode]"

Comment: How do you expect to get the name when name is nested inside the response object?

Comment: You need to go inside the response object, events array, iterate through the events array to print out each name.